# rails g kaminari:views bootstrap3が実行できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

railsでgem 'kaminari'を導入した後に、bootstrap3との競合を避けるために、
＄rails g kaminari:views bootstrap3
をしたのですが、以下のエラーが出てきて困っております。どなたか対処法を知っていたらぜひご教授お願いします。

```
rails g kaminari:views bootstrap3
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/kaminari-core-
1.0.1/lib/generators/kaminari/views_generator.rb:114:in `initialize': 
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
https://api.github.com/repos/amatsuda/kaminari_themes/
git/refs/heads/master (Errno::ENOENT)
```

多分、railsのヴァージョンを最新のものではなく、ダウングレードすれば解決できるかなと思い、5.0.4や5.0.2にしたものの同様のエラーが出ました。困り果てておりまして、ぜひ何か知っている方や同様のエラーが出ている方はコメントしていただけたら、嬉しいです...

（参考：Railsチュートリアルでrails newするときはバージョンを指定しよう）
http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/f3bde6e46afbeba8cb82

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/88821

Answer (score 2):

**状況整理：**

エラーメッセージをよく見ると、実際の処理を実行せんとして 失敗しているファイルとその該当行が出力されているのがわかります(ファイルパス:該当行 形式)

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.0.1/lib/generators/kaminari/views_generator.rb:114

あと、理由として、ファイルないしディレクトリを開こうとして存在していない、とも言っています

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

しかし、該当ファイルを実際に開いてみて、行を見てみるとわかるのですが、開こうとしているのはファイルやディレクトリではなくURL です...!!

そこで、その前後を直接編集してしまえば、もしかしたらエラーの回避は可能になるかもしれません

**対応：**

すこし弄ってみたところ、`require 'open-uri'` を追加してあげると、コード中で指定されているリモートのリソースを読み込んでくれるように動作が変わってくれました
(114行目周辺、`def get_files_in_master` の1行下)

本来であれば当該 GitHub リポジトリにissue を書いたりPull Request を送るべきですが、そういうのをすっ飛ばして解決したい場合、その場しのぎとしては有効かもしれません

(Ruby 2.4.1, Rails 5.1.3 で検証)

Comment: ありがとうございました。色々見ていただき本当に助かりました！

Answer (score -2):

> railsでgem 'kaminari'を導入した

とあるので bundler を利用しているとおもうのですが、

`$ bundle exec rails g kaminari:views bootstrap3`

としてみても同様でしょうか